# Fuchs - Fomenko, Exercise 1.

Tags: general-topology

In their book "Homotopical Topology", Fuchs and Fomenko introduce $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ as the set of all real sequences which have only finitely many non-zero entries, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^\infty = \{(a_i) \ | \ a_i \in \mathbb{R} \ \text{and} \  a_i = 0 \ \text{for all but finitely many} \ i\}$. Topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows: a set $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed if and only if all the intersection $F \cap \mathbb{R}^n$ are closed in respective spaces $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then we are given Exercise $1$, which is the following: Show that a sequence $(a_1, 0, 0, ...), (0, a_2, 0, ...), ..., (0, ..., 0, a_n, 0,...),...$ has a limit if and only if it has only finitely many nonzero terms.

My reasoning is as follows: $(\implies)$ Let $S$ denote the set of all the elements of this sequence. Then $S \cap \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed for all $n.$ Therefore, a limit of this sequence cannot lie outside of the set $S$. Hence, it has to lie in $S$. If $(0, ...,0, a_k,0,...)$ is a limit of this sequence, then the set $S' = S - \{(0, ...,0, a_k,0,...)\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ (since for all $n$, its intersection with $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists of finitely many elements and is therefore closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Therefore, the complement of the set $S'$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ that contains $(0, ...,0, a_k,0,...)$ and doesn't contain any other distinct terms of this sequence. Hence, all but finitely many terms of this sequence have to be the same as the element $(0, ...,0, a_k,0,...)$. If $a_k \neq 0$, this is impossible given the way this sequence is constructed. Therefore, $a_k = 0$ and so all but finitely many terms of our sequence have to be the zero element $(0, ..., 0, ...)$.

$(\impliedby)$ Obviously, if all but finitely many terms of this sequence are zero, then zero is a limit of this sequence (I keep saying "a limit" since I don't know if this space is Hausdorff and so I'm not sure if limits are unique).

Note: there is a similar question on this site and I have read the question. I have not, however, read the answer since I'm afraid it might contain a solution to this problem. I don't want a solution to this problem. I would appreciate if anyone could check my reasoning and if the reasoning makes no sense, then please provide with a line or two explaining where I messed up. I will then go back to working on this problem. Reading solutions outright usually ruins the day for me, so I would truly appreciate your help. Thanks.